# Question identity theorem accumulation points

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that you only know that the complex exp function is entire and $e^{x+y}=e^{x}e^{y}$ for real $x,y>0$. Proof that $e^{z+w}=e^{z}e^{w}$ for all $z,w$ in C. First choose y>0 fixed and look at the holomorphic functions $f(z)=e^{z+y}$ and $g(z)=e^{z}e^{y}$.

My idea was the following. 
Choose y>0 fixed. {z in C|$e^{z}e^{y}=e^{z+y}$} has a accumulation point so $e^{z}e^{y}=e^{z+y}$ on C from the identity theorem. 
Choose z in C fixed. {w in C|$e^{z}e^{w}=e^{z+w}$} has a accumulation point so $e^{z}e^{w}=e^{z+w}$ on C from the identity theorem.

My problem is that I don't see how to explain that the given sets have a accumulation point. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I think we can prove $e^{z+w}=e^ze^w$ in another way. So, you are saying you want to prove it in your way?

Answer (score 3):

First note that $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$.

The idea is that every $\epsilon$-neighbourhood (in this case I mean the $\epsilon$-ball $N(x,\epsilon)$ defined in $\mathbb{C}$) of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ intersects $\mathbb{C}$ non-trivially.

Also there's another theorem that you can use (Prove it using the identity theorem).

**Theorem:** If $f$ and $g$ are entire functions and $f(x)=g(x)\ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f(z)=g(z)\ \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$.